# React js how i can hide private scripts in Login Page

Tags: reactjs

When I access the login page which is a public route that does not need authentication, all scripts from my private components are imported.
Is there a way to not show the scripts of the private components when accessing a public route?
In this case, when I access the login page, all the scripts for the home component are loaded in the browser.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your concern with this, exactly? Typically, authentication protects your data, not your code.

Answer (score 1):

> all scripts from my private components are imported

As it should be.

> Is there a way to not show the scripts of the private components when
>   accessing a public route?

There is no such thing as `private` component. Everything is loaded with webpack or any other bundler. Its not a bad thing. Now, if you want to hide content in component you can store relevant data in some authorized api with persistent storage and then when user logs in, goes to that specific component, data can be fetched and processed.

Comment: code-splitting, if applied appopriately, would solve this problem.

Comment: Do you mean `React.lazy` and `dynamic import`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
i noticed that i dont have private component, but i can use react lazy load, to not loading scripts that i'm not using in specific route

https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html